# Trying to use css modules and getting a Unexpected token error @ the dot in .navbar {

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to use css modules in my project so that I can do the following in my components:

```
import styles from './styles.scss';

...

<Navbar className={styles.navbar}>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error when I try to run my `server.js` file:

```
> babel-node src/server/server.js

/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:600
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /home/arthas/dev/test/src/components/navigation/header/styles.scss: Unexpected token (1:0)
> 1 | .navbar {
    | ^
  2 |   -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  3 |   -moz-border-radius: 0;
  4 |   border-radius: 0;
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4246:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1627:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3586:12)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:6402:22)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3331:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3311:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3241:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3218:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3181:19)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/home/arthas/dev/test/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:5694:20)
```

Here's how I've set up the specific loader in my `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: 'style!css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss!sass'
  }
```

Comment: Might be worth checking if there's an invisible character like a byte-order-mark at position #1

Comment: Hey Phil.  Just tried that and nothing unfortunately :(

Comment: I'm thinking this is not a issue in my config, but something with babel?  I've got everything set up correctly I think in my .babelrc:  `"presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],`